# unable to find edit template control checkbox in row command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound, rowcommand

I tried to get the control of edit template which is checkbox in row command event but I am unable to get it, but I am getting label control which is in row index.

I tried the above below code to get the control:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

    Label icllbl = (Label)GridView1.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("icllbl");
    CheckBox iclcb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("iclcb");

    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
    {                
        if (icllbl.Text == "Y")
        {
            iclcb.Checked = true;
        }

    }
}
```

And I tried RowDataBound event also luckily I am getting checkbox control here but this time I am unable to get the Label control in below code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label icllbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("icllbl");

        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {

            CheckBox iclcb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("iclcb");
            if (icllbl.Text == "Y")
            {
                iclcb.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a `Windows form application`?

Comment: Nope, it is a website @gdmanandamohon

Answer (score 0):

In your RowCommand event use `control` class to cast into `GridViewRow`:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
```

And in RowDataBound event place `Label` control inside Edit (check for EditTemplate) check:

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
{
    Label icllbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("icllbl");
    CheckBox iclcb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("iclcb");

    //... other code of lines will be here
}
```

Comment: well i have tried your way which is the same code i have posted, you had just used that label inside the edit state. This will not work because once the Gridview is in Edit state it cant read the item template control